# publish an ontology like dbpedia

Tags: ontology, dbpedia

after I had created my ontology how can publish it ?
I want to have the same look of dbpedia ontology
http://dbpedia.org/page/Italy
thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a very broad level, if you are using java, you can create a servlet and a standard HTML template to create a page like the one you have linked. You can use an ontology API like OWL-API or Jena or in fact write your own xml parser that takes a .owl file in and spits out each tag and the information contained therein. The servlet then takes the HTML template and populates it based on however you choose to logically organize the data.

For the HTML template, you can directly use the html code from the dbpedia page you linked.

For tips on how to deploy this solution, we need to know more about where you want to publish this page.